# why GET method does not work while POST works for same api calll in express?

Tags: express, mongoose

I got confused while running my code.
I am trying to make an API route for searching books and when I apply POST method it works and does what I want to achieve while there is nothing in body but when I apply GET method it shows following error:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "search" (type string) at path "_id" for model "bookmodel"
    at model.Query.exec (E:\FullStacks\BookStore\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4803:21)
    at model.Query.Query.then (E:\FullStacks\BookStore\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4902:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: '"search"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'search',
  path: '_id',
  reason: BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer
```

what could be the reason behind it?
route:

```
router.get("/search", bookcontoller.searchBook)
```

```
async searchBook(req, res) {
    try {
      const { query } = req.query;
      console.log(query);
      if (!query) {
        return res.status(400).json({ success: false, msg: "query not found" });
      }

      const searchResult = await bookModel.find({$or:[{name:{$regex:".*"+query+".*"}}, {genre:{$regex:".*"+query+".*"}}]})
      if(searchResult.length == 0){
        return res.json({success:false, msg:"nothing found of that query"})
      }
      return res.status(200).json({success:true, msg:"search has been successful", searchResult})

    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(400).json(error);
    }
  }
```

url:

```
localhost:8000/book/search?query=hi
```

Comment: It's much harder for people to help you when you don't show the actual code that causes this error.  But, the specific text of the error is indicating that you're passing some argument that doesn't meet a certain criteria in the query or passing something that then leads to that situation.  Please show the code for the `searchBook` method and show the exact incoming URL when that route is called.

Comment: i updated the code please review

Comment: Given the accepted answer, shouldn't you have seen that `console.log(query);` was not executing and that it wasn't even hitting the code you're showing?

Comment: what you guys are talking is going above my head but logging `req.url` in searchBook() does not log anything, error is same and server crashes but by rearranging routes according to Robert, the problem got fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You very likely also have a route looking like this:

```
router.get('/:id', ...)
```

And the handler of that route uses `req.params.id` to perform a query on `bookModel` to find the book with that id.

Then, you declared the route you're showing:

```
router.get('/search', …)
```

Express does not pick the *best* route handler that matches, but the *first*. And a request for `/search` will match the route for `/:id` just fine. So you're performing a query against `bookModel` using the word "search" (now in `req.params.id`) as `_id`, which fails because that's not a valid `ObjectId`.

The solution is to always declare *more specific* route handlers first:

```
router.get('/search', …)
router.get('/:id', …)
```

Comment: As to your solution, I favor restructuring the URL scheme to avoid mixing wildcard routes with any other routes on that part of the path since it just sets you up for future conflicts.  Reordering is a temporary solution, but sometimes just sets you up for namespace issues where future URL path segments now conflict with legal id values.

Comment: @jfriend00 fair point. In case of ObjectId's, I prefer matching them explicitly (`router.get('/:id([a-fA-F0-9]{24})', …)`, off the top of my head)

Comment: Yeah, that could work also by making it so it isn't a "matches everything" wildcard route and lives in a restricted namespace.  For a real wildcard that could be anything, I do something like `router.get('/id/:id', ...)` where it is given its own namespace in the URL structure and thus no future conflicts possible.